# Is there a way to stop user credentials caching with Spotipy?

Tags: python, flask, spotify, spotipy

I am using spotipy to create a small web app. I have everything working fine, but would like to implement a log out / log in button.
From looking through the spotipy and spotify endpoint api docs, i can't seem to find a way to stop the users credentials caching.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? i would like it so the user has to log in every time they open the webpage.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT - i get (and cache) the credentials:

```
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="clientid",
                                               client_secret="secretid",
                                               redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000/",
                                               scope="playlist-modify-public playlist-read-private playlist-modify-private user-library-modify"))
```

Comment: How are you saving the tokens now? Caching would be on your end and dependent on what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

almost two years late, so sorry, but it would appear the only way to stop using the .cache file is the following

when you make your oauth object, in a function,

```
def spotipy_oauth(ci, cs, ru, sc):
    return spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth(client_id=ci, client_secret=cs, redirect_uri=ru, scope=sc)
```

you get the access token with the `spotipy_oauth().get_access_token(code)` right

in the `.get_access_token()`, you can do `.get_access_token(code, check_cache=False)`

this disables the cache. note, however, that spotify will auto log people in if they're set to remember me. not really a way around that one

if you're reading this and still lost, you get the code with the `spotipy.oauth().get_authorization_url()`, which sends the user to the login page, which then after login, gives a code in the url bar. to get it in flask, you say `code = flask.request.args.get('code')`